# Mountain Lion: How do I see the description of a software update after I've installed it?

Tags: macos, software-update

When OS updates are available in the app store, there is usually a short description near the update button. Is there a way to see this description after I've installed the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Purchases tab in App Store and click on a software title, the description of the app is presented in all its full glory, with screen shots, customer ratings & everything else.